# Is it possible to to define a volume usable both in k8s and docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume

If I want to run a container `B` within a container `A` (reusing the Docker daemon) I can just bind mount `/var/run/docker.sock` and `/usr/bin/docker` and can happily call `docker run` within `A`.
Now I would like to share a k8s volume between `A` and `B`. For that I thought of creating an emptyDir volume in `A` and pass it to `B` using `docker run -v`. But this does not work as the emptyDir volume does not seem to be a Docker volume (it does not appear when running `docker volume ls`).

The snippet below prints a list of volume where `cache-volume` does not appear:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: test-container
    command: [ash]
    args: ["-c", "docker volume ls"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
    - name: dockerlib
      mountPath: "/usr/bin/docker"
    - name: cache-volume
      mountPath: /cache
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
  - name: dockerlib
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/bin/docker
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

So the question is: is there any way to define a volume usable both in k8s and docker?

Answer (score 2):

For the record I found a workaround but if you have a better suggestion please don't hesitate to share it.

A solution to the problem above is to mount a hostPath directory `D` and bind mount this directory into the container `B`.

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd3
spec:
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: test-container
    command: [ash]
    args: ["-c", "echo blabla > /home/test.txt ; docker run -v /home:/home --entrypoint ls alpine /home"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
    - name: dockerlib
      mountPath: "/usr/bin/docker"
    - name: home
      mountPath: "/home"
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
  - name: dockerlib
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/bin/docker
  - name: home
    hostPath:
      path: /home`

The result of the above snippet is that `B` now has a `/home/test.txt`, which is what we wanted.